# Storing image data (fonts) in hexadecimal format in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to modify this code (http://code.google.com/p/pypng/source/browse/trunk/code/texttopng) so that it can render extended ASCII symbols. Currently I'm trying to figure out how storing the fonts in hexadecimal format works, but after extensive googling around I haven't been able to understand it, nor extend it.

And another problem I'm trying to solve is to render even multi-line documents with this script. I'm thinking it's something to do with this line of code

`return x,y,itertools.imap(lambda row: itertools.chain(*row),
                              zip(*map(char, m)))`

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, don't do that. It is somewhat obscure, esoteric, hard to read and very limited, as you have noticed yourself. The [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) offers text rendering to PNG and JPEG using Freetype2, which is a much saner and feature-complete approach.

Now we have that out of the way, the representation is quite simple and by the way also explained in the [documentation of the png module](http://packages.python.org/pypng/png.html) in the standard library:

> There is a fourth format, mentioned
>   because it is used internally, is
>   close to what lies inside a PNG file
>   itself, and has some support from the
>   public API. This format is called
>   packed. When packed, each row is a
>   sequence of bytes (integers from 0 to
>   255), just as it is before PNG
>   scanline filtering is applied. When
>   the bit depth is 8 this is essentially
>   the same as boxed row flat pixel;
>   [...] This format is used by the
>   `Writer.write_packed()` method.

Basically, the bits in the integer value ranging from 0-255 specify if a given pixel in that row is on/off. Using the `char` function out of the very same code, try visualizing it by executing something like this in your favorite Python shell:

```
for row in char("A"):
    print bin(row[0])[2:].zfill(8)
```

You should end up with output like the following:

```
00000000
00111000
01000100
01111100
01000100
01000100
01000100
00000000
```

...which is more visible in a monospaced terminal font, but still should be pretty obvious.